# C++: Compiler instantiate template function only on demand?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following simple template function:

```
template <typename T>
int compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    if (lhs<rhs) {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (rhs<lhs) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My course lecturer explained that when we use a template function, we should specify, either implicitly or explicitly, the template argument to bind to the template parameter:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main() {
    // implicitly specifying that T is int
    cout<<compare(2,3)<<endl;

    // explicitly specifying that T is string
    cout<<compare<string>(string("something"),string("another"))<<endl;
}
```

This process of deducing the right template is called "instantiation"; the actual template argument is used to generate a specific instance (in this case - a function) of the appropriate version to be run later at runtime.
He also mentioned that the instantiation happens "on demand"; for example, the last code segment will produce two instances of the compare function, one for `int` and one for `string`.
This made me wonder, why would the compiler complain about something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;


template <typename T>
int compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    if (lhs<rhs) {
        return x; // deliberate compile-time error; x cannot be resolved
    }
    else if (rhs<lhs) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    // no calls for compare are made here
}
```

You'd think that the compiler shouldn't have any problem with the above compile-time error, since compare never gets instantiated. However, this will not compile...
Since no template argument was provided, this template function allegedly doesn't make any sense to the compiler (this is a simple compare function, but think about a template function that lies heavily on the template arguments' types...)
So what exactly is "instantiation" then?

Comment: In your first paragraph: When your teacher said "explicit", he didn't mean "deduce". Template type deduction **is** the implicit way to know what `T` is. (In other words, there is no such thing as *explicit template type deduction*.)

Comment: I'm sorry, the right phrase would be "specifying, either implicitly or explicitly"... I'll correct the main post.

Comment: If you replace `x` by `lhs` the code does compile.

Comment: If you use `<string>` you don't need `string("blah")` as well.

Comment: @NeilKirk, I know, it was for demonstration purposes... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the compiler sees your template, it already parses and analyses it *to some degree*. What exactly is already done is quite complicated, but among other things, (template parameter independent) **name lookup** takes place. This means the compiler already tries to figure out what `x` is, and he fails.

An example what the compiler does *not* try to resolve is what exactly `T::x` is, because it **depends** on `T`, your template parameter. The expression `x` *does not depend* on any template parameter, that's basically the key difference why `x` fails to compile and `T::x` [will succeed](http://ideone.com/4XV7s6):

```
template <typename T>
int compare(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    if (lhs<rhs) {
        return T::x;
    }
    else if (rhs<lhs) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Of course, with most types `T` this will fail to *be instantiated*, but that's not the key here. You can even write a template for which the instantiation fails for all `T`, but that's out of scope for an answer to this question.

Comment: I believe the standardese calls it "name lookup".

Comment: @T.C. Thanks. I never know the wordings. :)

Answer (score 1):

§ 14.6 [temp.res]/p10, emphasis added:

> If a name does not depend on a *template-parameter* (as defined in
>   14.6.2), **a declaration (or set of declarations) for that name shall be in scope at the point where the name appears in the template
>   definition**; the name is bound to the declaration (or declarations)
>   found at that point and this binding is not affected by declarations
>   that are visible at the point of instantiation.

Unlike the general rule that a template is ill-formed if no valid specialization can be generated for it, violation of this rule requires a diagnostic (since it has no "no diagnostic required").

In your code, `x` is a non-dependent name, so the `compare` template violates this rule, and a conforming implementation is required to generate a diagnostic.